# Enzyme .getDOMNode().scrollBy() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

Hello im working on testing a scrollbar of div with jest + enzyme 
i have an error saying "is not a function" when i try to access scrollBy() function of that div

My code :

```
it('One step scroll working', function() {
      wrapper.find('#slider').getDOMNode().scrollBy(40, 0)
      console.log(wrapper.find('#slider').getDOMNode().scrollLeft)
})
```

Im testing this simple component :

```
<div id='slider' className='yard-cs'>
    {this.props.children}
</div>
```

error :

```
TypeError: wrapper.find(...).getDOMNode(...).scrollBy is not a function

      26 |  it('One step scroll working', function() {
    > 27 |         wrapper.find('#slider').getDOMNode().scrollBy(40, 0)
         |                                              ^
      28 |         console.log(wrapper.find('#slider').getDOMNode().scrollLeft)
      29 |   })
```

this div contains some text and is scrollable ! so why the function is not working ? thanks

Comment: `jest` uses `jsdom` for DOM operations. `enzyme` does not extend it, so if some method is missed you have to mock that [on your own](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom) or try to find existing package doing that for you

Comment: I tried that solution that you gave me from jest documentation ! i don't have the error now but it's not working ! the function does nothing